# Show that interval $(a, b)$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: metric-spaces

I know that interval $(a, b)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. To show that interval $(a,b)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, I have done so: Let it be $x\in (a,b)$. Enough to find an open ball containing the point $x$, and that is included in the interval $(a,b)$. Suffice to get $0<\epsilon\leq \min \{\vert b-x\vert, \vert a-x \vert\}$. In this case $D(x,\epsilon)$ containing the point $x$ and $D(x,\epsilon)\subseteq (a,b)$. I do not know a good act. If it is that I did very well then correct, but I do not know how to prove this fact: *To show that interval $(a,b)$ is not open in $\mathbb{R^2}.$*

Please if anyone has the opportunity to help, to make verification of keti example, thank you preliminarily

Comment: Some would say that $(a,b)$ isn't even a subset of $\mathbb R^2$. The product $(a,b) \times \{0\}$ is, however.

Comment: In any real or complex valued  vector space $V$ one may define for any $a,b\in V$ the interval between $a$ and $b$ as the line segment between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: In that sense intervals may be open iff $\dim(V)=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As kahen pointed out, what you want to say is that $$(a,b)\times\{0\}$$ is not open in $\Bbb R^2$. Now, pick any point ${\bf x}=(x,0)$ with $a<x<b$. Then $B({\bf x},\varepsilon)$ contains elements of the form $(x_1,x_2)$ with $x_2\neq 0$ (prove this!), so $B({\bf x},\varepsilon)$ cannot be contained in $(a,b)\times \{0\}$. This means $(a,b)$ is not open, since we've found a point (actually all of them) that are not interior points. In fact, ${\rm int}_{\Bbb R^2}\;(a,b)=\varnothing$.

Comment: thanky sir, thanks for your attention, and your help, excuse me, since I do not know the solution, I wish to ask, is this complete solution, thank you

Comment: @MadritZhaku Yes, this is the "complete solution."

Answer (score 1):

suppose Interval $(a,b)$ is open  in $\mathbb{R}^2$ then  Its complement $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus (a,b)$ must be closed, so  $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus (a,b)$ contains all its limit points.

but $ x_n=({a+b\over 2},{1\over n})$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus (a,b)$ and $x_n\to ({a+b\over 2},0)$ which is a point in open interval $(a,b)$ on $X$ axis so we get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $x + \frac{\epsilon}{2}(0,1) \in D_\epsilon (x)$...

As $x + \frac{\epsilon}{2}(0,1)$ has a non-zero $y$-coordinate, it is not in $(a,b)$.

**P.S.** If $a,b$ are not real numbers, but points in $\mathbb R^2$, you can do the same by replacing $(0,1)$ by an unit vector $u$ such that $u \perp {ab}$.

Comment: Would the downvoter explain what is wrong with this hint?

Comment: I do not even know to give negative votes, sorry but if you think that I have done such a thing did not know what to tell you, I have not done and for that you provide

Comment: @MadritZhaku Don't worry I wasn't refering to you. Someone downvoted this answer, which means someone thinks this answer is wrong. I would love to find out what is wrong with it.

Comment: ok sir, if you please give me the opportunity to detejuar and complete solution, please do, thank you

Comment: @MadritZhaku Pedro already provided the missing details in my hint ;)

Comment: @N.S. With that reference, I understand what your hint is getting at, but I must say I didn't understand it at first. Maybe you can add the non-zero second coordinate detail. =)

Comment: @N. S. there are other reasons to downvote a reason other than it being wrong - doing a student's homework for them, showing off, excessively complicated solutions.  I think those are all _better_ reasons for downvoting. By the way, I didn't downvote your answer.